# Espaço indesejado na pagina ao criar media queries

Tags: css3

Estou criando um site com layout responsivo,quando o site entra na resoluçao mobile sobra um espaço abaixo indesejado

```
@media(min-width:176px) {
div#rodape{
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align:center;
}
}

@media(min-width:320px) {
div#rodape{
width: 100%;
height: 230px;
text-align:center;
}
}
```

/*OBS. este site nao é meu isto é apenas um exemplo*/
[image]

Comment: O CSS na tua pergunta não é suficiente para causar o que aparece na captura de tela. O espaço terá que ser proveniente de alguma falha na _markup_ ou uma definição de CSS que não as que constam na tua pergunta. Deverás atualizar a pergunta com a informação relevante à analise do problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando usa media queries tem de ter em atênção o minimo e máximo que faz com que o browser escolha uma parte do código ou outra.

Aí vejo que está a defenir `min-width` nas suas queries, para ambos. Eu sugiro que mude para:

```
@media(max-width:319px){
    /* ... */
}
@media(min-width:320px){
    /* ... */
}
```

Assim a fronteira entre um e outro fica defenida e não concorre uma com a outra.

Comment: As declarações na media `@media(min-width:176px)` estão sempre em vigor salvo se alteradas na media `@media(min-width:320px)`, [ver exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/t82tg27k/). Um `text-align:center` na primeira não precisa ser declarado na segunda se for para manter o alinhamento ao centro. Mas o problema do OP parece ser uma margem enorme ou um espaço que um elemento antes do `#rodape` ocupa. De qualquer forma, falta informação na pergunta... por exemplo: de onde vem o fundo preto do rodapé? E se isso está declarado, que outras declarações existem?

Comment: Muito bom @Sérgio li muitos artigos a respeito dos "conflitos" das Media Queries e isso passou despercebido, Agradeço desde já.

Comment: @LamborghiniAventador o comentário do Zuul faz muito sentido também, por vezes é util ter `min-width` em ambos mas consciente que algumas regras do mobile pervalecem no desktop.